# Android+I need to show only facebook??@share intent dialog list

Tags: android

Android+I need to show only facebook list item in the share intent pop up not all the list of several sharing apps..can it be done??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook SDK and call that directly as opposed to using a share intent.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/

[android facebook api post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093618/android-facebook-api-post)

Comment: Can we only show the facebook link/button in the share intent dialog?? removing or disabling other social medias??

Comment: That's not the purpose of the share intent. The share intent is used to share data with a user's network by whatever application can accept the data type, but that being said - I believe Twitter can be filtered out ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application - see the second answer ) but I'm not sure about Facebook.